# In keras how to deal with multi inputs in fit but one input in pred?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm transplanting a net from tf1.x to tf.keras. In tf1.x the loss is calculated like below:

```
forward = Seq2Seq()

#part1
pred_raw = forward.make_unet(x)
loss_bce = loss_fun1(pred_raw, ylable)

#part2
ul_logit = forward.make_unet(ul_x)
d = fun1(ul_logit)
logit_m = forward.make_unet(ul_x + d)
r_vadv = fun2(logit_m)
logit_v = forward.make_unet(ul_x + r_vadv) 
loss_vat = loss_fun2(ul_logit, logit_m, logit_v)

#
loss_all = loss_bce + loss_vat
```

Part1 is easy to transplant, but how to add part2?

Maybe setting `ul_x` as another input and set `ul_logit`,  `logit_m`, and `logit_v` all as outputs worked, but in pred, I just need one input `x` and one output `pred_raw`, so I don't think it's a good way, is there any better method to deal with this?